# Remove bottom border in selected Tab

Tags: android, tabs, border

My question is just what the title says.
So I have it like this:

[image: I have it like this:]

And I want it lke this:

[image]

Any possible fix to this? I'm developing for Android 1.6 (API level 4)
Thanks a lot

EDIT: Another option for what I want could be to remove the entire bar. Is this possible?